# Preventive measures for duplicate entries VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, duplicate-data, duplicates

I have a UserForm that adds new items to my inventory sheet.

I would like to seek help on if I could make my product like a primary key. So that the "product key" cannot be duplicated. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

My code is as follows in the link (Can't seem to paste my code in this box as i keep getting an error saying my code isn't properly formatted)*sorry for the inconvenience*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/enNJr.jpg

```
Option Explicit 

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click() 

    Dim row As Long 
    Do 
    row = row + 1 
    Loop Until (Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 1) = "") 

    Sheets("Inventory").Select 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 1) = txtProdCodeAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 2) = txtProdNameAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 3) = txtQuantityAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 4) = txtSupplierAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 5) = txtSupplierNumberAI.Value 

End Sub 

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click() 
    Unload AddInventory 
End Sub
```

P.S code has been added to picture description in the link but not formatted properly

**

- Edit

**

The user enters the product code, product name, quantity, supplier(name) and supplier contact number through a textbox.

The primary key is on column A and starts on row 2 as there is a header.

The sheet name is call "Inventory".

If the same primary key is entered there will be an error popup "vbokonly - Error! Product code already exists. Kindly use Update feature."

Comment: It would be helpful to have added details. How is the information being entered into the userform? Which column in the worksheet contains the "primary key"? What should happen if a user enters an item into the userform that is already in the "primary key" field? I think the question needs is a bit too ambiguous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check for the value in column A:

```
txtProdCodeAI.Value
```

Like so:

```
Dim keyExists as Boolean

keyExists = Not Range("A1:A" & row).Find(txtProdCodeAI.Value) Is Nothing

If keyExists Then
    MsgBox txtProdCodeAI.Value & " already exists!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Put it in your code like so:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click() 

    Dim row As Long 
    Dim keyExists as Boolean
    Do 
        row = row + 1 
    Loop Until (Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 1) = "") 

    keyExists = Not Sheets("Inventory").Range("A1:A" & row).Find(txtProdCodeAI.Value) Is Nothing

    If keyExists Then
        MsgBox txtProdCodeAI.Value & " already exists!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Sheets("Inventory").Select 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 1) = txtProdCodeAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 2) = txtProdNameAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 3) = txtQuantityAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 4) = txtSupplierAI.Value 
    Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 5) = txtSupplierNumberAI.Value 

End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004':

I have a method 'Range' of object'_Global failed.

Debugging brings me to the line

keyExists = Not Range("A1:A" & row).Find(txtProdCodeAI.Value) Is Nothing

Comment: what is the value of `row` when you run the code. NB that this is a snippet that will need to be placed *within* your existing code, after the assignment to `row`.

Comment: Oh! oops I was careless! I put my row below it. Thank you very much! And may i ask. How do I copy my code into the tread? I always encounter errors when copying my code to this website

Comment: May I also get help whereby besides showing the ProdCode, it also shows the respective ProdName as well?

Comment: `MsgBox txtProdCodeAI.Value & " - " & txtProdNameAI.Value & " already exists!", vbCritical`

Comment: After that line, you can also do: `txtProdCodeAI.Value = vbNullString` and `txtProdCodeAI.SetFocus`.  That will clear out and return the cursor to that text box.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/58zEfjO) If its possible, Maybe it could retrieve the value from the table itself instead of the txtbox. :)

Comment: change the hyphen to a colon. to retrieve the Name, you'll use the `Vlookup` function against the table.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution in excel, you can use validation format in the entire column, in the *empty* column, select the entire column and go to **Data Tab** > **Data Validation** > and there:

[image]

That will restrict all the values you input (similar scheme as primary key, no dupes)but with this it will prompt an Error (as you can't enter repeated values), so in your cycle you need to add an Error handler like this (**untested**)

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Sheets("Inventory").Select 
Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 1) = txtProdCodeAI.Value 
Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 2) = txtProdNameAI.Value 
Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 3) = txtQuantityAI.Value 
Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 4) = txtSupplierAI.Value 
Sheets("Inventory").Cells(row, 5) = txtSupplierNumberAI.Value  
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "This Product Code" & txtProdCodeAI.Value & "is a duplicate" 
Resume Next
```